# using a tail and a buffer to get last K lines in a file

Tags: python, file, buffer, tail

I was given this buffer and told to make a reverse input that get the last K lines in a file. From what I've been trying to do, every time I tried to run the code it says that used is not an attribute of Input. Can someone please tell me why this keeps happening? Thank you in advance.

```
class Input:
def __init___( self, file ):
    self.file = file # must open( <filename>, "rb" )
    self.length = 0
    self.used = 0
    self.buffer = ""
def read( self ):
    if self.used < self.length:  # if something in buffer 
        c = self.buffer[self.used]
        self.used += 1
        return c
    else:
        self.buffer = self.file.read( 20 ) # or 2048
        self.length = len( self.buffer )
        if self.length == 0:
            return -1
        else:
            c = self.buffer[0]
            self.used = 1

     `
```

Comment: Post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code demonstrating your problem. Your question is missing relevant information in its present form, such as how you are instantiating and using the `Input` class, not to mention on what input. Also, paste the literal error your program returns, outputs or throws, do not just retell it.

Comment: Indentation is incorrect, `__init__` is incorrect with 3 underscores instead of 2. Fix them before others can help you.

Comment: I'm betting the problem is in the wrong name for `__init__`. That means it never gets run, so the `used` attribute never gets set on the instances. Since it is the first attribute accessed in `Input.read`, it complains that there is no attribute `used`.

Comment: Well @HaiVu was correct. Thank you, kindly. Cannot believe I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and try guessing that the problem is that you are using the wrong name for the `__init__` magic method (as noticed by [Hai Vu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459745/hai-vu)). Notice that there are three trailing underscores in your code instead of two.

Since the `__init__` method is the one called during the construction of the object to set its various attributes, the `used` attribute never gets set because the `__init__` function never gets run.

Afterwards, `used` is the first attribute accessed in Input.read, which makes Python complain about it being missing.

If I'm right, remove the underscore and it will fix the problem (though there may be others).

Comment: Hardly worth posting such a detailed explanation for a question that's going to get closed as a simple typo.

Comment: It was several sentences to type which took a minute or two. I got the feeling the question asker was a beginner so I tried using this as a learning opportunity for him. If it's deleted, it's deleted, it's not a big waste.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. :)

Comment: @dkasak , thank you for taking the time.  If it gets closed fine. I missed it. I am a beginner and I'm still trying to wrap my head around interacting with classes and objects.

Answer (score -1):

Try indenting...

```
class Input:
    def __init___( self, file ):
        self.file = file # must open( <filename>, "rb" )
        self.length = 0
        self.used = 0
        self.buffer = ""
    def read( self ):
        if self.used < self.length:  # if something in buffer 
            c = self.buffer[self.used]
            self.used += 1
            return c
        else:
            self.buffer = self.file.read( 20 ) # or 2048
            self.length = len( self.buffer )
            if self.length == 0:
                return -1
            else:
                c = self.buffer[0]
                self.used = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, pasted into the text weirdly. In my file it is indented properly.